# Python while loop error - condition ignored by python?

Tags: python, while-loop

Here is the code I am running:

```
#Import torsions.dat
f = open("torsions.txt")
next = f.readline().strip()
length = next                       #Store the first line as length

#Store the values for phi and psi in lists
phi = []
psi = []
while next != "":
    next = f.readline().strip().split(" ")
    phi.append(float(next[0]))
    psi.append(float(next[1]))
```

But I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpWC2.png)

The file torsions.txt contains this:

20

60 61

62 63

64 65

---

There is no space after 65. There are 4 succeeding lines (i.e. there's no blank line in between). THe underscores are just for clarity, they're not in the txt.

The loop stops the script due to the error, adn the part after the loop doesn't run. 
phi and psi get populated as required, but then the loop should stop, but it looks like it doesn't.

Could you help?

Comment: Please copy and paste the error in your question rather than uploading a picture

Comment: Why do you assume that it just has to be an empty string that could throw the error? Any non-numeric value could be in there. And anyway, the `while` loop condition is checked prior to _redefining_ `next` so it doesn't stop an invalid string getting through to the `float` conversion.

Comment: Actually I think I understand your thinking. The `while` condition is checked as "do I start this whole loop again?" as opposed to checking at every stage whether the condition is true.

Comment: The issue is resolved - square brackets were required in the while loop, i.e. NOT ' ', but [' ']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`next = f.readline().strip().split(" ")`

readline will return an empty string `''` when done reading the file.

`split` will give `['']`, and you can't convert `''` to a float.

Also `[''] != ''`.

Comment: Thanks - the very last line of your answer is what solved it.
Code should read:

while next != [' ']: